# pricing encrypting RDS with KMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, key-management

i want to encrypt my RDS instance from Amazon Web Service but i dont know the explanation of the pricing.

It says that each API request of AWS Key Management Service costs $0.03 per 10,000 requests.

Every query means an API request or every connection ?

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are encrypting your RDS storage volumes, using the default kms/rds key, then you will pay $1/month for the key, but your API requests will be negligible.

If you look at the KMS pricing example for EBS, the key is only used when creating the volume.  It should be the same for RDS.

Update:  This is not 100% correct.  There will be a KMS call every time an encrypted volume is attached to an instance, which means every time you reboot an RDS instance you should have a KMS call.  But overall cost should be negligible, and you should not be at risk of hitting any sort of query limits.